# AVPlayer plays online resource but not same downloaded resource

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayeritem

I have an audio file downloaded from server to my documents directory. I'm trying to play the same using AVPlayer in swift but some reason unable to do so. Below is my entire code. If we replace  `localAudioPath` with `onlineResource` it plays fine

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class AudioController: UIViewController {

  var player : AVPlayer!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  @IBAction func playAudio(sender: AnyObject) {
    var name = "bell.mp3"
    var docs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(directory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
    var localAudioPath = docs.stringByAppendingPathComponent(name)
    var onlineResource = "path/to/online/bell.mp3"

    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(localAudioPath!) {
      let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: NSURL(string: localAudioPath!)!)
      player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
      player.play()

    } else {
       /* Alamo fire code to download file to docs directory*/
      let destination = Request.suggestedDownloadDestination(directory: .DocumentDirectory, domain: .UserDomainMask)

      Alamofire.download(.GET, NSURL(string: audio.audioUrl)!.http, destination)
        .progress { (bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead) in
        println(totalBytesRead)
      }
       .response { (request, response, _, error) in
        println(response)
      }
   }
  }

}
```

Can someone tell me if it's even possible to play local files using AVPlayer ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30471885/2303865

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use fileURLWithPath: to provide the correct url and it should play the local url just fine.

```
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: localAudioPath!)!)
```